# Drupal statistic module doesn't work

Tags: php, drupal

I have localhost and live website. When i had tried to enable statistic module, error appeared (error that says "accesslog" table already exists), and module was enabled, but there was no settings page link on drupal main configuration page.

What i did for localhost, i have switched off the module, removed "accesslog" table and another one table "node_count" (i found info about that plugin creates that table too).

And everything works at my local PC.

The problem is - I don't want to remove that tables on my live website. Because i afraid that any other module could use that DB tables ("accesslog" was empty, but "node_count" contained some entries). Is there any fix for that module?

Should i try to update core? I have 7.15 version.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the `module_name.install` file to make it so that it doesn't try to create the new database tables upon install. In that install file you should see a function name `function module_name_schema()` just comment out the `return` at the bottom. Example:

```
function module_name_schema() {
    //some arrays here for the tables
    return $schema; //could be another variable name just put // in front to comment it out
}
```

You might want to look at those arrays creating the tables though and make sure the schema they are defining is the exact same as the schema of the tables already in the DB otherwise you will get a lot more errors.